# doesn't work .buttonset() on jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, wordpress-theming

I have a number of :checkbox elements that are initialized by a wordpress. Now i set .buttonset() function to #format but this is not work... like this sample:http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox

HTML:

```
<div id="format">
     <?php
     $categories = get_categories();
     foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
     <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="<?php echo $category->cat_ID; ?>">
     <label><?php echo $category->cat_name;?></label><?php } ?>
     *//ADD STATIC HTML:*
     <input type="checkbox" id="id" /><label for="id">B</label>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#format').buttonset();
$('input[type=checkbox]').removeClass('ui-helper-hidden-accessible');

$(':checkbox[name=check]').each(function( i ){
    var nameID = 'check'+ (i+1);
    this.id = nameID;
    $(this).next('label').prop('for', nameID); 
});
```

if i'm added  a :checkbox element  with static HTML it's worked well.

`<input type="checkbox" id="id" /><label for="id">U</label>`

and this is generated HTML:

```
<div id="format" class="ui-buttonset">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="3" class="check" id="check1">
          <label for="check1">
          <span class="ui-button-text">CAT1</span>
          </label>      
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="4" class="check" id="check3">
          <label for="check3">
          <span class="ui-button-text">CAT2</span>
          </label>              
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="5" class="check" id="check4">
          <label for="check4">
          <span class="ui-button-text">CAT3</span>
          </label>              
     <input type="checkbox" id="id" class="">
          <label for="id" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-right ui-corner-left" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false">
          <span class="ui-button-text">B</span></label>

</div>
```

Comment: You are not closing your <input> tag. ALso by the way what's with `$('input[type=checkbox]').removeClass('ui-helper-hidden-accessible');`

Comment: <input type="checkbox"; you need to close it after each label right,,

Comment: working good here http://jsfiddle.net/MmjDc/ if `.removeClass` line commented.

Comment: This must have something to do with something on your rendering from PHP. I don't see the error yet, but looking at a JS rebuuild of it, i'm having zero troubles. See my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/WnELF/). I present before and after buttonset HTML. maybe it can help you figure out your issue?

Answer (score 0):

you didn't close your input type checkbox in your php code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="<?php echo $category->cat_ID; ?>"/>
```

Comment: looks closed to me? it doesn't "have" to end with `/>`